# alterar a pasta de download do dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Já consigo utilizar a variável como nome do arquivo de download, mas não consigo alterar a pasta de download, sempre baixa na pasta download.

Comment: está muito confuso. explica melhor, coloque alguma parte do código e aponte onde está sua dúvida, por favor.

Comment: Nessa parte: $dompdf->stream($name.'.pdf', array("Attachment" =>true)); 
Não consigo definir o diretório que será baixado. Vou utilizar para gerar o relatório na minha própria maquina.

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta contém muito pouco a respeito do seu problema o ideal é você dar mais detalhes, mas vamos tentar ajudar, você está tentando definir a pasta para o client-side? Se sim, você não tem como dizer ao client onde ele vai forçar o download por stream, sempre vai salvar onde o usuário disser pra salvar, só é possível definir o local em seu servidor. Se eu estiver no seu server você pode dizer para ele assim:

```
  $dompdf->stream("pasta/doc/documento_para_download.pdf", array("Attachment" =>true));
```

Comment: Não, estou usando isso para gerar o relatório interno para minha empresa, quero gerar o relatorio em pdf para uma determinada pasta. 

Esta aspa depois do pdf está fechando onde?
Não consegui.

Comment: Então é o usuário que deve definir o local de download. Me desculpe o erro, as aspas depois do .pdf abrem antes da palavra pasta, dentro dos parênteses.

Comment: Então, mas é para nosso empresa que esotu fazendo, nos que iremos imprimir o relatório, e quero que sempre que clique em gerar relatórios ele baixa dentro da pasta com os arquivos do site, entendeu?

Já tentei desse jeito, e vai para o download também!
Obrigada.